# Datatype to store 20 digit number

Tags: java, math, numbers, type-conversion, base36

I have a number of 20 digit, which datatype will support to store this number? I have tried long, double but I 'm getting out of range.

Number = 48565664968483514466

Then I have to convert this number to Base36 to generate the barcode.

Comment: BigInteger - when I'm trying to use new BigInteger(number), I'm getting literal of type int is out of range.

Comment: Are you doing any numeric manipulation on the number?

Comment: BigInteger i = new BigInteger("48565664968483514466");

Comment: @brso05 - I need to convert this number to BASE36 to generate barcode.

Answer (score 15):

```
BigInteger:
```

The `BigInteger` class allocates as much memory as it needs to hold all the bits of data it is asked to hold and  also provides operations analogues to all of Java's primitive integer operators and for all relevant methods from `java.lang.Math.`

Declare it as

```
BigInteger bi1 =  new BigInteger("12345678900123");
```

Answer (score 4):

To convert your number in base 36:

```
BigInteger number = new BigInteger("48565664968483514466");
String numberInBase36 = number.toString(36);
System.out.println(numberInBase36);
```

Answer (score 2):

> when I'm trying to use new BigInteger(number), I'm getting literal of type int is out of range

The syntax you are looking for is

```
BigInteger n = new BigInteger("48565664968483514466");
```

with the numeric literal as a `String`, since the primitive integer literals cannot hold a number this large.

Answer (score 0):

```
BigInteger i = new BigInteger("48565664968483514466");
```